# How to acceed to an item td and click on it

Tags: html, vba

I am not familiar with html but I'd like to click on a button and do this from vba. I read a tutorial about how to search info on a HTML webpage from vba and then I tried it for my case but it's a little bit different.

The interesting part of the html code is the following one : [html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiev6.png)

What I did it to first identify a part which I could access easily. I thought the form which has the unique name result was a good start.

Then in this form appears only once the classname "resultRow" so I also used it to my advantage.
I am now in the right table and see that whatever the element I click on is, the onlcick result is the same. So I choose to select a random item ( number 4) and to click on it.

Unfortunately I made something wrong.

Here is my code

```
 Sub my_code (ByVal faul As String)

Dim IE As Object
Dim IEAPuMA As Object
Dim side As String
Dim IEDok As HTMLDocument
Dim Element As IHTMLElement
Dim Form As HTMLFormElement

Set IEAPuMA = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEAPuMA.Visible = False
side = "my_website"
IEAPuMA.navigate side
Do While IEAPuMA.readyState <> 4
Loop

IEAPuMA.Visible = False
Set IEDok = IEAPuMA.document
Do: Loop Until IEDok.readyState = "complete"
'Schleife über alle Elemente der Seite
Set Form = IEDok.all("result")
Form.getElementsByClassName("resultRow").Item(4).Click


End Sub
```

can someone help me out ? And maybe propose an easier way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Form.getElementsByClassName("resultRow")
```

will return a collection of all elements with a matching class, so it will give you a collection of `tr` elements.  If you wanted to access the individual `td` elements below that, you would need something like:

```
Dim tr, tds

Set tr = Form.getElementsByClassName("resultRow")(0)'<<first match

Set tds = tr.getElementsByTagName("td")

tds(4).click '<< fifth cell
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will check this and post here the result :)